# How can i change my BIOS password?

Tags: bios, passwords, password-recovery, secure-boot

I have tried everything, backdoor passwords, flashing the bios and bios reset tools
made by my manufacturer (which is HP). All fail to work. I'm trying to install Kali Linux but I have secure boot on and it won't let me boot in the USB I made. if there are any ways around either of these, please let me know.

Comment: are you seriously suggesting that you flashed the BIOS and it still asks you for a password?

Comment: @barlop Probably UEFI, not BIOS, in which case yes, that happens. Passwords and Windows key are stored elsewhere and aren't deleted or reset even if flashed.

Comment: The OP needs to contact tech support.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia This site does offer tech support. What do you think this site is doing?

Comment: @barlop It's implicit the manufacturer's (HP) tech support (and provide proof of ownership).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia what is implicit?

Comment: @barlop It was implicit in my comment above, *The OP needs to contact tech support*

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You mean that "HP" was implicit in your comment, But why do you say HP specifically. Are you suggesting that there is no solution that can be offered here? if so, why would you say there is no solution that can be offered here?

Comment: @barlop If there's a solution here I'm yet to see it. I've seen many many similar questions and no solution. Perhaps you can post a duplicate? Yes, I meant HP's, the manufacturer's tech support was implicit. I'll make sure to make it explicit next time.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so how do HP solve that kind of thing then with their HP machines?

Comment: @barlop That I don't know. I'm just repeating what olfred said lots of times.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia who is "olfred" ?

Comment: Sorry, typo... I meant "oldfred": https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-reset-bios-administrator-password/m-p/6126028/highlight/true#M3115702  Ouch!!! $215,49 for the service?

Comment: Tried booting with the hard drive removed / unplugged?

Comment: Do you get a code if you enter the wrong password 3 times?, if so please post it

Comment: @moab yeah, I tried that with https://bios-pw.org/ but to no avail. I know with older machines there's a switch on the board to reset the password, but with laptops? I have no idea. ill take a look when I get home. And $215.49 for the service? that's crazy. maybe copying over the Kali Linux install files to a partition on the hard drive would be a better option.

Comment: @barlop Yes, yes i am.